# How to stop automatic time update?

Tags: time

I want to know is there any way to stop automatic time update permanently in Ubuntu 12.04 .

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click on the clock, and then select time and date settings

[image]

And then select "Manually"

[image]

You can also ensure the ntp package is not installed (clicking on the button will show if you if you have it installed or not:

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: will the changes continued after restart also ?

Comment: yes, they should.

Comment: yeah i will let you know with a restart . I think NTP not installed .thank for the information .